# Fix wifi connection since windows 1903 update

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Since the 1903 windows 10 update, my wifi connection has been spotty.  The wifi will drop internet connection intermittently and within 30 seconds reconnect itself.

I am using Dongle TP-Link T3-U & Google OnHub.  All drivers installed and updated etc. And was working fine until the update.  Other devices on wifi do not have this issue.

Network solutions online did not work.  I thought of using a 3rd party wifi connection (connect to wifi not through native windows 10 connection) but I could not find any online?

What is the best method to get a steady wifi connection.

Comment: What is a "3rd party wifi connection" in this context? You mean a different Wifi Dongle? Also the Windows update is very unlikely to be the cause of your problems in this case. Have you performed a site survey to see what interference and existing channels are present? These tend to change over time and may require re-configuring your own network to compensate.

Comment: The best method to get a steady wifi connection is to perform a site survey and ensure both your wifi access point and wifi adapter have enough transmit power to overcome any local interference. Using the 2.4ghz band will help if there is a lot of physical objects impeading the signal between them. Meanwhile using the 5ghz band will help if the 2.4ghz band is crowded or filled with EMI.

Comment: I updated the post.  Bypass the windows 10 wifi connection and connect through a different program.  I think I used one years ago but dont see any around now.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, there's no such thing. There are 1st-party wifi tools for _managing_ your wifi connection... usually provided by the manufacturer of your WIFI adapter. But the actual connection is done by windows itself... always. There's no bypassing that.

Comment: A site survey?  I am 2 meters from the wifi point with no interference.  All the other devices connecting to wifi work perfectly.  And my phone testing the signal - shows strongest possible signal from the position of my dongle

Comment: a site survey is usually more involved than that... but given that you are 2 meters from the access point and other devices are working... it's probably not signal issues